# Can I have a default memberwise initializer for a class in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

Let’s say I have a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
   let bar: String
   let baz: String
}
```

Do I really have to write the memberwise initializer by hand?

```
init(bar: String, baz: String) {
    self.bar = bar
    self.baz = baz
}
```

It’s pure boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

If you can work with value semantics instead of reference semantics, you can use a Struct instead of a Class, they have automatic memberwise initializers.

[image]

If not, then you *have* to provide the full init yourself for your class.

Comment: Thanks! My class really needs to be a class. Is there a reason why the automatic memberwise initializer is not supported with classes?

Comment: You're welcome. And no, I don't know why exactly. Please keep us updated here if you find out. :)

Comment: There’s a [memberwise initializer proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0018-flexible-memberwise-initialization.md) with links to further discussion that makes this a bit more clear. It looks like the deficiency is acknowledged, but not to be solved in the near future.