# Is it possible to have default member initialization with a class in Swift (like with a struct)

Tags: swift, class, struct, initialization

In the following example code, I create a struct and a class with similar members.  With the struct I can initialize an instance by any number of the members into its constructor, and the rest will default.  With a class, I have to specify every version of init I want to use.  Seems like I must be missing some way to do it with a class though -- is there any way to do this?  It looks like in [2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078063/can-i-have-a-default-memberwise-initializer-for-a-class-in-swift) there was not, but I know Swift has changed a ton since then.  I'm hoping there is a way now.

```
import Foundation

struct FooStruct {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title = ""
}

// these statements both work fine
let a = FooStruct(id: UUID())
let a2 = FooStruct(title: "bar")

class FooClass {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title = ""
}

// these statements both give the same error:
// Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
let b = FooClass(id: UUID())
let b2 = FooClass(title: "bar")
```

Comment: There isn't :( but if you're using Xcode, you can have it write it for you https://www.vadimbulavin.com/generate-memberwise-initializer/

Comment: *It looks like in 2016 there was not*. There was always.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander -- I didn't know about that -- I don't really want to have to have the full init in code, but if I don't have to type it at all, that's better at least.  Appreciate the reference :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing with Structure types is what is called a memberwise initializer. Swift does not provide one of these to Class types because of the more complex way Classes are initialized, due to their inheritance model.

Swift provides a default initializer—different than a memberwise initializer—for any structure or class that provides default values for all of its properties and doesn’t provide at least one initializer itself. The default initializer simply creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their default values.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use this:

```
class FooClass {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var title = ""
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), title: String = ""){
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

and this will work:

```
    let b = FooClass(id: UUID())
    let b2 = FooClass(title: "bar")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer -- I should've been more clear in my question, I knew I could do this, but trying to avoid it for a class with many more members.  Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

you can just generate memberwise initializer easily by right-clicking class name and select refractor->Generate Memberwise Initializer
[image]